# Division Tie breaker

Tags: american-football, nfl, tie-breaker

OK, I think there is a simple answer, but my buddy and I just can't agree. If Patriots and Dolphins were both 10-6....but the Dolphins beat Pats twice...YET..the Pats had a 4-2 Divison record while Dolphins were 3-3. Who would win the Division. My buddy says Dolphins cause they beat pats twice and they both have same overall record. I say the Division record trumps the head to head. Please we need your input

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong. This is very clearly explained to the NFL's [tiebreakers page](http://www.nfl.com/standings/tiebreakingprocedures):

> Two Clubs
>
> 1. Head-to-head (best won-lost-tied percentage in games between the clubs).

i.e. the head to head record is the first tie-breaker to be applied.